# Cygwin: Make Issues

Tags: c, linux, unix, cygwin

Hello StackOverflowers!

I'm trying to simply make and test the following program from GitHub [C- Compiler](https://github.com/javelinjs/C-Minus-Compiler) but I'm having issues making the lex file. I am using cygwin, and I am attempting to do this to compare input and output from my own C- Compiler.

I am extremely new to this stuff but the error I'm getting is...

```
$ make lex
lex c-grammar.lex
make: lex: Command not found
makefile:5: recipe for target 'lex' failed
make: *** [lex] Error 127
```

Any and all help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Possibly you need to install lex...

Comment: Most likely you haven't installed lex.  Run the cygwin installer again and when the package list shows up search for lex.

Comment: You want to do something like this: https://youtu.be/Y8OOizmGLw8 except you want to search for lex and not sqlite.

Comment: I'm guessing flex = lex?

Comment: @BeccaBohem a `flex` package probably gives you a usable `lex` command, yes.  It's not quite right to say `flex` = `lex`, but the details are probably more than you want to hear right now.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you are spot on in that assumption!

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have installed flex, but am still receiving the error, any ideas for me?

Comment: @BeccaBohem, you haven't given us much to go on, but `flex -l` has behavior very close to that of traditional `lex`.  You may be able to update your Makefile to use that instead.  Look especially for a make variable named `LEX` -- if it's present then set its value.  If not, then it might work to create it: near the top of the file, insert something like `LEX = flex -l`.

Answer (score 0):

the `lex` command is missing on your system.  You can install the package `flex` to provide that command.  You may need to create a symlink `/bin/lex -> /bin/flex`.  That should do it.  Chances are you will end up needing the `bison` package as well.